# Problem installing httpd-devel

Tags: web

I'm trying to install phusion passenger on my CentOS server on Media Temple (dv4). However, I have 3 missing dependencies when trying to install httpd-devel.

```
--> Missing Dependency: httpd = 2.2.3-53.el5.centos.3 is needed by package httpd-devel-2.2.3-53.el5.centos.3.i386 (updates)
httpd-devel-2.2.3-53.el5.centos.3.x86_64 from updates has depsolving problems
--> Missing Dependency: httpd = 2.2.3-53.el5.centos.3 is needed by package httpd-devel-2.2.3-53.el5.centos.3.x86_64 (updates)
Error: Missing Dependency: httpd = 2.2.3-53.el5.centos.3 is needed by package httpd-devel-2.2.3-53.el5.centos.3.i386 (updates)
Error: Missing Dependency: httpd = 2.2.3-53.el5.centos.3 is needed by package httpd-devel-2.2.3-53.el5.centos.3.x86_64 (updates)
```

Seems like I'm missing `httpd=2.2.3-53.el5.centos.3`, but I have no idea how to find out what's the current version I have, and how to update it.

Comment: Hi there, OS questions are generally best off asked at serverfault.

Answer (score 1):

you have mixed 32 and 64 bit libs installed, sometimes the devel libs conflict because they want to install files that are common to both the x86_64 and .i386 version. (and presumably having 2 httpd packages would conflict because they want to listen on the same port, but I have not tried that...;-)

start by trying to install either the 64 or 32 bit dependencies, so help the phusion installer.

```
yum -y install httpd-devel.x86_64 httpd.x86_64
```

if that doesn't work you should look to try to install the correct passenger by passing the arch.

```
yum -y install mod_passenger.x64_64
```